# Do AudioKit nodes pass signal with a volume greater than "-0dB" or does it get clipped?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I have a small technical question about the way AudioKit passes its signals around from node to node:

If I were to say, create a sound source that was producing a signal above "0dB" (let's say it's producing +4db audio)– a signal that would peak if it were going straight to speakers, when that node is connected to another node (say, a compressor):

**Does the compressor node receive the full level of the signal and can operate accordingly, or does producing peaking / clipping signals actually clip them at 0dB from the output of the node itself?**

I'm asking universally how the gain stages work when passing from AKNode to AKNode- therefore things the AK oscillators, effects, filters, mixers, etc.

I've been extensively using rolling plots to check that my levels are behaving as expected, but this clarification would be enormously helpful

Any insight would be hugely appreciated- thanks!